# Telegram Bot Webhook doesn't track channel post deletion

Tags: telegram, telegram-bot, telegram-webhook

I need to synchronize telegram channel posts with my site. So, I created a bot, a channel, added my bot to this channel(with admin rights, it has access to messages) and binded my bot's webhook to the specified server url. Everything goes well, post creation updates are correctly sent to the server url. The only problem is that the update of channel post deletion from telegram is not tracked, so admin has manually delete posts from the server database. Any idea, how to set up bot or webhook in order to track post deletion?

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible using [Bot API](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api/) since Telegram doesn't send most of the events to Bot accounts.

You should instead use [MTRPOTO](https://core.telegram.org/mtproto) to connect to a number on Telegram as a normal user (not a bot) that is the admin or subscriber of that channel and receive all of the events from Telegram.

I'd suggest you use [Telethon](https://docs.telethon.dev/en/latest/) (A Python MTPROTO library).

Upon a message deletion, you will receive `MessageDeleted` [event](https://docs.telethon.dev/en/latest/modules/events.html#telethon.events.messagedeleted.MessageDeleted).

There's an example on Telethon's document website:

```py
from telethon import events

@client.on(events.MessageDeleted)
async def handler(event):
    # Log all deleted message IDs
    for msg_id in event.deleted_ids:
        print('Message', msg_id, 'was deleted in', event.chat_id)
```

---

But if you insist on doing this with bot API, there's a spaghetti solution. You can forward channel posts to another chat with their Ids, if you get a message doesn't exist error, that means the message was deleted.

Comment: Maybe you have a decision in PHP? I don't code in Python

Comment: @АртемПаламарчук You should check [MadelinePROTO](https://docs.madelineproto.xyz/), I haven't worked with it but it has good documentations to help you begin.